# How to solve $\sin{14x} - \sin{12x} + 8 \sin x - \cos{13x} = 4$?

Tags: trigonometry

Find all solutions of $$\sin{14x} - \sin{12x} + 8 \sin x - \cos{13x} = 4$$ on an interval $(0^\circ, 360^\circ)$

Comment: What identities about $\cos$ and  $\sin $ you know ?

Comment: @Nizar i could simplify $sin{14x}$ into $sin({7x + 7x})$ and with much, much more complications probably get the result, but could it there be a simpler way?

Comment: Please  edit your question  adding  what did you try (as you said in the above comment), this at least helps you not taking such downvotes!

Comment: @user296914: Welcome to MSE. Please add your own solution to the question. :)

Answer (score 6):

Using the trigonometric identity $$\sin A-\sin B\equiv2\cos\frac{A+B}2\sin\frac{A-B}2,$$with $A=14x$ and $B=12x$, we can write the equation as $$(2\sin x-1)(\cos13x+4)=0.$$The general solution is therefore $$x=n\pi+(-1)^n\frac\pi6\quad(n\in\Bbb Z).$$For the range you specify, $x$ is $30^\circ$ or $150^\circ$.